# Enable rotation while open a pdf file

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, extjs, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to enable rotation while the pdf is open Using the `window.open()` method to open pdf file in ios cordova application?

```
window.open('path.to.local.pdf', '_blank','EnableViewPortScale=yes,location=no,closebuttoncaption=DONE,toolbarposition=top');
```

The rotation while using the cordova app is disabled  but i want to enable the rotation while the pdf file is open. is it possible?